# Access modifiers on properties; why doesn't the following work?

Tags: c#, properties, access-modifiers

I've run into a compiler error that doesn't quite make sense to me. I have an `internal` property and I want to restrict its `set` block such that it is only available through inheritance. I thought this would work:

```
internal bool MyProperty {
    get { return someValue; }
    protected internal set { someValue = value; }
}
```

But the compiler says that the access modifier on the `set` block needs to be more restrictive than `internal` - am I missing something, or is `protected internal` *not* more restrictive than `internal`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`protected internal` is *less* restrictive; it is protected **or** internal (not **and**) - which therefore *additionally* allows subclasses from other assemblies to access it. You would need to invert:

```
protected internal bool MyProperty {
    get { return someValue; }
    internal set { someValue = value; }
}
```

This will allow code in your assembly, plus subclasses from other assemblies, *get* it (read) - but only code in your assembly can *set* it (write).

Comment: Great explanation; makes perfect sense to me now.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) on Access Modifiers in C#:

> **The protected internal accessibility
>   level means protected OR internal, not
>   protected AND internal.** In other
>   words, a protected internal member can
>   be accessed from any class in the same
>   assembly, including derived classes.
>   To limit accessibility to only derived
>   classes in the same assembly, declare
>   the class itself internal, and declare
>   its members as protected.

To achieve the desired effect, you instead need to swap the access modifiers, like so:

```
protected internal bool MyProperty
{
    get { return someValue; }
    internal set { someValue = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's the union of the two, not the intersection; hence `protected internal` is less restrictive than both of those individually. The intersection isn't a feature of C#; the CLR does support "Family AND Assembly", but C# only supports "Family OR Assembly".

Answer (score 1):

Here, `protected internal` is less restrictive that `internal`.

- `protected internal` - public for current assembly and any type that inherits this type in other assemblies.
- `internal` - public for this assembly and private for other assemblies